# How does ["$field"] in PHP work?

Tags: php

Hi I have problem understanding the code below:

```
foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) { 
   $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
   $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&'; 
}
```

What does `$this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value` do? I need some examples to understand this.

Comment: Uh, what's `paypal` code? do you mean `php`?

Comment: The code is taking some data POSTed to it from a form, stuffing it into an object attribute, and appending it to a query string. It's poor quality code. `["$field"]` is cargo-cult programming, and the query string can be generated far more efficiently by other methods.

Comment: @RiaD that's [the cargo-cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) bit to which MarcB was referring.

Comment: @Michael, sure, I skip it for some reason, deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line:

```
$this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
```

needs to be understood in context. The $this keyword refers to the current object in which the code is executed.

For example, consider this:

```
<?php

class Car {
    private $make = "Toyota";
    private $model = "Corolla";
    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->make . " " . $this->model;
    }
}

?>
```

In your case, the $this->ipn_data is a member of the class, and is an array. The $field is being set as the key in the array and the $value is assigned to that new key in the ipn_data array.